# Removing New Line Character from field name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

I somehow managed to get a newline character into a field name when using MySQL with Django. What is the easiest way to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This was quite a frustrating issue for me, as most of the usual syntax (using \n for example) did not fix this issue. I eventually found out that this works:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE `
fieldname` `fieldname` varchar(80);
```

Basically, you have to manually enter a newline before the field name, and they must be in backquotes because mysql otherwise ignores line feeds.